# React Close one dropdown when the other is open

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I was looking at similar questions, but none of them was suitable for my issue.

I want to close an active open dropdown when the other is getting open.

It's simple to code to keep open multiple dropdowns but how to make them close once you open the other?

my code snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-currying-1tx3ut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move **isOpen** and **setIsOpen** to the parent component, so you can control all the select components.

Instead of using setIsOpen(true/false), you will use setIsOpen(section.id) so you know which section is active.

At last, you can check `isOpen === section.id` to see which section is active and open it up.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-ride-9obomn?file=/src/SectionCard.js

Comment: jeezz that simple!
thank you very munch! Beer on me! :)